# Sudo won't accept my password even with Caps Lock off and the right password

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, password, sudo

First, I just want to say that I *did* check for caps lock and I know for a fact that it was the correct password and everything was fully correct. I even entered the `sudo` command a second time and double-checked that it was not misspelled or anything prior to pressing enter. Also, I made sure all other programme windows were closed.

It still didn't work. Why? Nothing changed, for only a few seconds ago I was doing the exact same command and it worked perfectly. Why now? What's going on?

Specs:

> Computer Model: HP Chromebook 11
>
> Booting Method: Croot via Crouton
>
> Crooted OS: Xubuntu 12.04.4

Comment: Try reloading the terminal emulator, and doing it again.

Comment: Have you changed the keyboard layout in the time?

Comment: @No Time: I already had tried that prior to posting this question. No cigar.

Comment: @Radu Rădeanu: No, I have not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `passwd yourusername` to see if you can change your password to try again with the previous command? You could also once you ran the previous command run `sudo passwd` to change unix password.

Comment: It just asks me for my password.

Comment: Is it accepting your password and letting you change it?

Comment: No, it doesn't accept my password. But nevermind, anyway. I didn't want to, but I had to uninstall Xubuntu because it was making it so that my Chromebook's energy output was greater than its charger's input. So...yeah... Thanks, anyway. Sigh... Dang it, I LIKE Xubuntu... :
(